# How to make double curve layout on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

How to achieve this dual-curved layout on Flutter?  `double.infinity` for height and width. Never mind about the Text and color, any color will do. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Column` with two `Flexible` widgets, both of them containing a `Stack` as a child, and two `Container` widgets in each. This way the containers will be on top of each other, and one of them can have a decoration with rounded corners:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: MyWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Stack(children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(100)),
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ))
          ])),
      Flexible(
        flex: 3,
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(100)),
          ))
        ]),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Peter Koltai you answered perfectly correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer @Peter Koltai you answered perfectly correct. Thank you